# Bootstrap Datepicker getDate does not return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/release/index.html) to create a booking form for some accomodation, but for some reason the getDate() is not working or being split properly,

The answer is probably obvious, but I can't figure out how to get the selected date as a string in the specified format and then split it into day / week / month as integers to append to a redirect URL.

I believe everything else is working except for being able to get the date,

```
var checkInDate
var checkInMonthYear
var checkInParts
var checkOutDate
var checkOutMonthYear
var checkOutParts


getRedirectURL = function() {

    $('#checkin').on('change', function() {
      var checkInString = $("#checkin").datepicker("getDate");
      var checkInStringSplit = checkInString.split('/');
      var checkInParts = {
          'checkInDate' : parseInt(checkInStringSplit[0]),
          'checkInMonth' : parseInt(checkInStringSplit[1]),
          'checkInYear' : parseInt(checkInStringSplit[2]),
          }

      var checkInDate = checkInParts.checkInDate
      var checkInMonthYear = checkInParts.checkInMonth + checkInParts.checkInYear;

    })

    $('#checkout').on('change', function() {
    var checkOutString = $("#checkout").datepicker("getDate");
    var checkOutStringSplit = checkOutString.split('');
    var checkOutParts = {
      'checkOutDate' : parseInt(checkOutStringSplit[0]),
      'checkOutMonth' : parseInt(checkOutStringSplit[1]),
      'checkOutYear' : parseInt(checkOutStringSplit[2]),
      }
    var checkOutDate = checkOutParts.checkOutDate

    var checkOutMonthYear = checkOutParts.checkOutMonth + checkOutParts.checkOutYear;
    })

var numberOfRooms = document.getElementById("numberOfRooms").value;
var numberOfAdults = document.getElementById("numberOfAdults").value;
var numberOfChildren = document.getElementById("numberOfChildren").value;
```

Comment: What is the value of checkOutStringSplit?

Comment: @00robinette when I declare it a global variable and add console.log(checkOutStringSplit) at the end of the script the console throws out undefined.